# Android, notification sound while app is minimized in android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_medico_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(msgBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setGroup(group)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msgBody))
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(notificationId++, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: check the device is volume not muted and not vibrated, but by default it wil lcome what ever the sound has given for notification it will come check, otherwise give some sound instead of defaultSoundURI.